# How to generate slug based on title of post in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am working on a project where I want to create a slug for each post based on its title. Is it possible to generate a slug in such a way that it will be unique to the post, but will not change even if the title of the post is changed? I am using the model provided in the file 'model.py'. Can you provide guidance on how to accomplish this?

```
class Post(models.Model):

    
    username = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(('Description'),max_length=250)
    title = models.CharField(('Content Title'), max_length=250)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    image_data = models.ImageField(upload_to='User_Posts', height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=None)
    slug = (title)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend checking out the Django documentation for [slugify](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify). You will need to override the save method of your model to do this, so your new code will most likely look something like this:

```
from django.utils.text import slugify
slug=models.SlugField()

def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
    self.slug=slugify(self.title)
    super(Post,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

I would keep in mind the unique parameter that you can set to either true or false in your slugfield.